# Maven Resources Compiler: Failed to copy in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04

My Java project builds successfully using Maven in Terminal.

When building using IntelliJ IDE the build fails for the same project.

it says **Permission denied**

```
Maven resources compiler: Failed to copy '/home/user1/development/git/oms/src/main/resources/application.yaml' to '/home/user1/development/git/oms/target/classes/application.yaml': /home/user1/development/git/oms/target/classes/application.yaml (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve that problem by giving permissions to the **target** folder recursively

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx target/
```

Answer (score -2):

Delete your `target` folder and run from `IntelliJ`. Make sure there is no Java process running your project already.

Comment: I deleted the target folder every time but the same result.